# How to disable more input in textarea based on height and width in angular 10?

Tags: html, angular, textarea

I am working with textarea in angular 10. In that I have set height and width of textarea. Also I have set no resizable style to textarea. So now I want to allow user to place text/content to particular that limited space of textarea. User should not allow to add more content then textarea height and width.

Problem is when I am entering text to area and width is over then it's allowing to enter text from user and horizontal content is increasing continuesly. Same thing is happen with verticlly contents. Space is finished but user can enter more content by pressing ENTER key.

```
<textarea *ngIf="field.fieldIsReadOnly===false" [ngStyle]="{'font-weight':field.fieldIsBold === true ? 'bold' : '', 
                                                            'font-style':field.fieldIsItalic === true ? 'italic' : '',
                                                            'font-size.px':field.fieldFontSize,
                                                            'font-family':field.fieldFontFamily,
                                                            'height.px':field?.fieldHeight>0?field?.fieldHeight:null,
                                                            'width.px':field?.fieldWidth>0?field?.fieldWidth:null,'resize':'none'}" class="field-width requiredTextField"
                                                            [attr.fieldId]="field.fieldID" [ngClass]="field.fieldID"
                                                            [(ngModel)]="field.fieldValue" required >
                                                            </textarea>
```

```html
<textarea _ngcontent-jqt-c69="" required="" class="field-width requiredTextField field3 ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-class="field3" fieldid="field3" spellcheck="false" ng-reflect-model="123456sfsaffffffffffffffffffff" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica; height: 67px; width: 317px; resize: none;">                                                            </textarea>
```

Please check snippest. I want to achive that it should not allow user to input more then area height and width. If user enter data and width is over then it should take new line and if height is over then it should not allow user to enter more content there.

Please guide me where should I place change ?

Comment: Are you looking for `maxlength` HTML property ? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: I have try with maxlength but it's also not working as per expactations. If I set maxlegth and width is 15px then user able to input text in single line upto maxlength and more then 15 px width.